# Collapsing every two columns into a final set of two columns

Tags: r

I have the below example_df, which has 4 "sets" of columns, each set has two columns in it. I essentially want a quick way to take every set of two columns and move the data into a resulting two columns (shown below in result_df, that is what I want to end up with). Any ideas on how to automate this?

```
set.seed(20)
example_df <- data.frame("test1" = c(rnorm(6), rep(NA, 18)),
                         "test2" = c(rnorm(6), rep(NA, 18)),
                         "test3" = c(rep(NA, 6), rnorm(6), rep(NA, 12)), "test4" = c(rep(NA, 6), rnorm(6), rep(NA, 12)),
                         "test5" = c(rep(NA, 12), rnorm(6), rep(NA, 6)), "test6" = c(rep(NA, 12), rnorm(6), rep(NA, 6)),
                         "test7" = c(rep(NA, 18), rnorm(6)), "test8" = c(rep(NA, 18), rnorm(6)))

result_df <- data.frame("total1" = c(example_df[c(1:6),1], example_df[c(7:12),3], example_df[c(13:18),5], example_df[c(19:24),7]),
                        "total2" = c(example_df[c(1:6),2], example_df[c(7:12),4], example_df[c(13:18),6], example_df[c(19:24),8]))
```

Comment: You are right, doing to much at once. Thanks for the comment and the solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options to create the expected output.

**1)** We create a 2 column `data.frame` by subsetting the alternate columns of 'example_df' (using logical index), `unlist` and remove the NAs

```
total1 <- na.omit(unlist(example_df[c(TRUE, FALSE)]))
total2 <- na.omit(unlist(example_df[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
d1 <- data.frame(total1, total2)
row.names(d1) <- NULL

#checking with the OP's output
all.equal(d1, result_df, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or in a single step

```
na.omit(do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, example_df[c(TRUE, FALSE)], example_df[c(FALSE, TRUE)])))
```

**2)** Loop through the sequence of columns in a `list`, subset the 'example_df', `rbind` the `list` elements with `rbindlist` and remove the NAs

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(seq(1, ncol(example_df), by =2), function(i) 
        example_df[i:(i+1)]))[complete.cases(test1, test2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
odd_cols <- as.logical(1:ncol(example_df) %% 2)

result_df <- data.frame(total1 = as.vector(apply(example_df[, odd_cols], 2, na.omit)),
                        total2 = as.vector(apply(example_df[,!odd_cols], 2, na.omit)))
```